# My code is returning two really weird errors

Tags: c++

My code isn't working. I  don't know why. The errors I am getting don't make sense.

> 17    18  C:\Users\the beast\Desktop\Case study phase 3.0.6.cpp   [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

I dont even know why it throwing this error.

> 77    1   C:\Users\the beast\Desktop\Case study phase 3.0.6.cpp   [Error] expected '}' at end of input

^ all brackets are present checked no idea why it is throwing this error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
//loading libraries
float const taxnet = .9;
float const taxwh = .1;
float employeenumber;
float payrate=0; 
float gross=0; 
float net=0; 
float manhours=0; 
float overtime=0; 
float taxes=0;
char usercontrols;

void data_loop(char usercontrols);
void writeWorkerInfo(ofstream &stream, float employeenumber, float manhours, float payrate, float gross, float taxes, float net);
void payrollcalc(float employeenumber, float manhours, float payrate, float     gross, float taxes, float net);
void data_entry(float employeenumber, float manhours, float payrate);
void data_recall(float employeenumber);
void data_error_check(char usercontrols);

int main(){

 // varibles
 cout << "Hit 1 to enter new data; hit 2 load a file; hit escpae to exit." <<  endl;
cin >> usercontrols;
while (usercontrols != 27){ 
data_error_check(usercontrols);
}
return 0;
}

 void data_error_check(char usercontrols){
cin >> usercontrols;
 if(usercontrols == 49 || 50){

        data_loop(usercontrols);
    }
    else if (usercontrols != 49 ||50){
        cout << "Wrong button hit enter to return to main menu" << end;
        cin >> usercontols;
        if(usercontrols == 13){

            main();
            }
        }
 }

 void data_loop(char usercontrols){
cin >> usercontrols; 

if (usercontrols == 49){
    data_entry();
}
else(usercontrols == 50){
    data_recall();
}
}
  void  writeWorkerInfo(ofstream &stream, float employeenumber, float manhours,   float payrate, float gross, float taxes, float net){
stream << " Your ID is                " << employeenumber << endl;
stream << " # of hours worked         " << manhours << endl;
stream << " Your Hourly rate is       " << payrate << endl;
stream << " Your Gross pay is         " << gross << endl;
stream << " Your tax rate is          " << taxwh << endl;
stream << " Amount of taxes           " << taxes << endl;
stream << " Your net pay is           " << net << endl;
data_loop();
}
 void payrollcalc(float employeenumber, float manhours, float payrate, float   gross, float taxes, float net){


if (manhours > 40) {
    overtime = manhours - 40;
    gross = ((manhours - overtime) * payrate) + ((payrate * 1.5)* overtime);
    //overtime claculation
}
else {
    gross = manhours * payrate;
    //no overtime calculation
}
taxes = gross * taxwh;
net = gross * taxnet;
//writeWorkerInfo(float employeenumber,float manhours,float payrate,float       gross,float taxwh,float taxes,float net);
std::string empnum = std::to_string(employeenumber);
ofstream payroll;
payroll.open(empnum + ".txt");
 writeWorkerInfo(float employeenumber,float manhours,float payrate,float      gross,float taxes,float net);
payroll.close();
}
 void data_entry(float employeenumber,float manhours,float payrate){
cout << "Enter Employee ID:";
cin >> employeenumber;
cout << "Enter Number of Hours Worked:";
cin >> manhours;
cout << "Enter Pay rate:";
cin >> payrate;
payrollcalc();
}
 void data_recall(float employeenumber){
cout << "Enter employee number";
cin >> employeenumber;
///reading in data
std::string empnum = std::to_string(employeenumber);
ofstream payroll;
payroll.open(empnum + ".txt");
payroll.close();
data_loop();
}
```

Comment: `main()` required a return type. it should be `int main(int argc, char** argv) {...`. you also can't define functions inside of another function.

Comment: Format your code and it will be obvious.

Comment: To avoid these errors, you should be compiling your code while you are developing it, and not wait until you've written the entire program.

Comment: You can't define functions inside other functions.

Answer (score 3):

Just get the functions definitions out of the `main` block code and call them inside `main`

Answer (score 0):

These points should explain why it's not working:

1. The function `main()` needs to return a type.
2. You are defining all your functions inside `main()`, place them above main or below with function prototypes.
3. You are using variables inside functions that aren't declared yet.

Answer (score 0):

Funtions are made so that it can be used in defferent place of the program, making it inside the main scope makes less sense!
Moreover we can't define funtion inside another function, we can just call it from nother fuction that comes after its declaration!

2ndly your main says nothing about returning.

```
ReturnType FunctionName (dataType args, ...){ FuntionBody}
```

Refer to the above syntax of a funtion declaration.
A `function` must always provide its `return` type as prefix or `void` if it dont return anything!

**Note:** In some compiler `void main()` works just fine, but some compiler says main should `return` something. So as a standard method you must define main as `int` not `void` to safegaurd urself.

Comment: updated the code going to bed

>Note: In some compiler void main() works just fine, but some compiler says main should return something. So as a standard method you must define main as int not void to safegaurd urself.

thanks man didn't know that